# how to validate passwords in viewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

```
[StringLength(255, MinimumLength=6, 
                   ErrorMessage = "Password can't be less that 6 characters"), 
                   Required, 
                   DataType(DataType.Password), 
                   Display(Name = "Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }

[StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 6), Required, DataType(DataType.Password), 
                   Compare("Password"), Display(Name = "Repeat password")]
public string RepeatPassword { get; set; }
```

If user enters password less than 6 & passwords don't match. Error message is :

> Password can't be less that 6 characters 'Repeat password' and
>   'Password' do not match.

if repeat password is less than 6 & passwords do not match error is:

> 'Repeat password' and 'Password' do not match. The field Repeat
>   password must be a string with a minimum length of 6 and a maximum
>   length of 255.

if this is the case I only want 'Repeat password' and 'Password' do not match to appear. How can I do this?

Comment: Remove `MinimumLength =6` from RepeatPassword

Comment: You do not have any seperate validation logic, or even a validation layer in place, do you?

Comment: @MicrosoftDN This wouldn't do exactly what he wants, but I agree that it is the standard thing to do. You will never get validation errors on password confirmations other then not matching

Comment: @MicrosoftDN thanks that give me the desired effect